# FlatList jumping to top of list when onEndReached called

Tags: react-native, pagination, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that fetches a list of jobs from the API. When the end of the list is reached on scrolling, the next set of jobs is fetched from the API and appended to the job list.

The following is the code for FlatList

```
<View style={localStyles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={jobList.jobs}
            renderItem={renderJobList}
            keyExtractor={item => "" + item.jid}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
            onRefresh={() => { getJobsList(true) }}
            refreshing={fetchingStatus}
            extraData={jobList.jobs, fetchingStatus, savedIds, stateChanged}
            ListFooterComponent={<ProgressIndicator inProgress={fetchingStatus} />}
            onEndReached={() => {
              getJobsList(false);
            }} />
        </View>
```

jobList, fetchingStatus, savedIds, stateChanged - these 4 are state variables

In the JobsListClass, the following is the code for appending the data -

```
        request.processRequest().then((value) => {
            this.jobs = this.jobs.concat(value.jarr)
            ...
            this.notify();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("campus err", error)
            ...
            this.notify();
        });
```

Have tried Array.prototype.push.apply(this.jobs, value.jarr); instead of jobs.concat in the above code but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I can‘t see what exactly cause the jumping, I would need more code to determine where this happen.

Take a look at the infinite scrolling expo [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/infinite-scroll-flatlist)

Comment: I looked at it and infinite scrolling is not the issue. Whenever the onEndReached is called, the new data is fetched and appended to my original data. So data wise there is no issue. It is just that the flat list jumps to the top when new data is added.

Comment: Can you post a complete sample?

Comment: I tinkered with the infinite scrolling expo snack and re-created my issue. In the rest of my code, when I was appending the data, I was changing the value of the state variable fetchingStatus along with the jobList.jobs. These together caused the list to re-render  and hence the list always started from the top when pagination occured.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, I have fixed the issue